# Why is Typename function so slow with Dictionary Class?

Tags: excel, vba

### My fellow VBA-elitists,

during my current Project i stumbled upon a problem with Dictionaries. Im using the [vba JSON Parser by Tim Hall](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) that uses [dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) to translate to json.

While digging into performance issues with nested dictionaries that have large first nests i identified the bottleneck in the TypeName call:

```
    If VBA.TypeName(JsonValue) = "Dictionary" Then ...
```

I Tested the typename with different types and none seems to be nearly as slow as a dictionary.
For example 1000 typename(dictionary) calls take about 400 milliseconds, whild typename(string) calls take like 2(!) milliseconds.

I tested other Objects aswell like Word Documents, Collections and other dll library objects like the [RegExp](https://software-solutions-online.com/vba-regex-guide/) Object, all about 2 milliseconds.

Any Ideas? Thanks <3

---

PS: I wrote my own little isDictionary Method, that checks if "dictionary.CompareMethod" is callable, interestingly with this method only the FIRST lap of the test now was 400 ms while the other 4 were 2 ms with now the bottleneck being when an Item of the Dictionary was called by the "Dictionary(Key)" Syntax.

It was nearly exactly as slow as if i had used the TypeName function, but only in the first lap :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer the Why, but as an alternative, and only if you are Early Binding to Scripting, it is faster to use `TypeOf` rather than `TypeName`

Eg

```
Function IsDictionary(o As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    IsDictionary = (TypeOf o Is Dictionary)
End Function
```

<sub>The Error Handler is to ensure `IsDictionary` returns `FALSE` if it's passed a non-object type</sub>

Comment: This is realy nice, thanks, i didnt know about "TypeOf" and didnt like typename string compare anyway. This operator is realy useful! i will create a new question for my second problem, cheers mate